# configuring an entity at runtime

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I am contemplating to write a generic user administration, that can be configured and operated through web services on Google App Engine. In particular it should be possible to add new fields, [similarly as in OpenERP](http://www.openerp.com/products/application_builder).

It seems to me that, [unless I want to use some CLOB trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881355/extending-jpa-entity-data-at-runtime),  the solution is not to use JPA at all and instead use Google App Engine native interface.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Add new fields to what ? a java class (which is what JPA is there to map) ?

Comment: @DataNucleus, I could have different versions being used at the same time by different users, maybe I should have something like a Map holding the fields.

Comment: Perhaps if you flesh out your question with an actual example, classes etc then it would be more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you are correct. JPA maps class fields to entity properties. If field is not there it will not map it.

However, you can avoid low-level API by using [objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/). It is a rich ORM, that provides a way to handle dynamic properties via [`@Embedded`](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Embedded_Maps) annotation on embedded Maps.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I was looking for. I already heard about objectify, but didn't try it yet. From a first look at Embedded seems what I am looking for. I will study and test objectify. Thanks Peter!