# How to create custom fields at runtime in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, orm

Is it possible in hibernate to create db fields at runtime.In my web project I need to implement logic in which a web user can create a form field.And to manage that new field we need to create a new field in database at runtime.If there is any other ORM framework that have such features,please suggest me.

Comment: Depending on 'who' the user is you don't want them to create fields at will

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending JPA entity data at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881355/extending-jpa-entity-data-at-runtime)